# Doctrine Associations Mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying Doctrine Associations with Symfony2 for the first time and it's giving me headache.

I have an Admin interface that can, among other things, upload images. I want to know which administrator uploaded what image so i've putted a foreign key `administrator` to my `images` table. To gather data, a simple JOIN is necessary to collect the data but with Doctrine, I'm stuck, altough it seems simple.

So, I have an `Administrator` object that reflects the table. In that object, I have this statement...

```
 @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ImageBundleNamespace\ImageEntity", mappedBy="administrator")
```

It's simple. In my `ImageEntity` object (that reflects `Images` table) is a foreigh key column `administrator`.

In the ImageEntity object, I use this statement...

```
 @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdministratorNamespace\Administrator", inversedBy="imageEntity")
 @ORM\JoinColumn(name="administrator", referencedColumnName="id")
```

There is a `administrator` field in `ImageEntity` and a `imageEntity` field in `Administrator` that the formentioned statements are mapping.

It doesn't work.

I've run the `SchemaValidator` on the EntityManger and it says the the `administrator` field on the `ImageEntity` object is not defined as an association. The second message says that the `administrator` field does not exist.

If it helps, this is my DQL for all of it...

```
'SELECT i.id,
        i.imeSlike,
        i.velicina,
        i.ekstenzija,
        i.paths,
        a.username,
        a.ime,
        a.prezime FROM ImageBundle:ImageEntity i
        JOIN a.administrator a'
```

Thank you in advance for all the help.

**EDIT**

I had a mistake in DQL. Corrected it.

**EDIT**

I forgot to add the source code. 
Association part of the Administrator...

```
**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Icoo\Administracija\GalerijaBundle\Entity\ImageEntity", mappedBy="administrator")
 */

protected $imageEntity;

public function __construct() {
    $this->imageEntity = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Association part of the ImageEntity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Icoo\LoginBundle\Entity\Administrator", inversedBy="imageEntity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="administrator", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */

protected $administrator;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the administrator class, you have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint")
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Icoo\LoginBundle\Entity\Administrator", inversedBy="imageEntity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="administrator", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
```

you need to remove the `@ORM\Column(type="smallint")`

This must be all. Let me know.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but if I remove that, then I have to copy table information to orm.yml file. Does that mean, if i use the doctrine associations with annotations, that i have to transfer table data mapping in an .orm.yml file every time i want to use associations?

Comment: I assume that if you use annotations on the entity, you defined annotation as the definition method. So, if this is the case, you only need to delete `@ORM\Column(type="smallint")` .

Answer (score 1):

You can separate field mapping from association mapping:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="administrator", type="smallint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
 */
protected $administratorId;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Icoo\LoginBundle\Entity\Administrator", inversedBy="imageEntity")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="administrator", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $administrator;
```

If you go further you can put exception into $administratorId getter/setter to avoid usage of it.

As i have tested, doctrine ignores value into $administratorId property when you persist/flush your entity (For confirmation you can look at prepareUpdateData() in Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister)

**EDIT**

I think, **my previous variant is possible but wrong.** Because, doctrine gets field mapping from definitions in referencedColumn, you can add some more definitions using

```
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="administrator", referencedColumnName="id", unique, nullable, onDelete, columnDefinition, fieldName)
```

This means that your `image_entity.administrator` field in db will be the same as your `administrator.id` field in db (except of additional definitions)

Comment: This is a really good answer. I'll try it tomorrow but i think it has to work. Just to understand better, $administratorId is not really a field in the database table, but an entity object holder for joined objects. Did I understood that correctly?

Comment: @MarioLegenda `$administratorId` is entity-object property which holds plain ID value (as string or as int). When doctrine loads object from DB it will fill this property, but you shouldn't use it in your php app code, because doctrine will persist to DB only value from `$administrator` property (which holds an entity-object of joined table). In your app you should only `get()` or `set()` `$administarator` property.

Comment: @MarioLegenda `$administratorId` and `$administrator` are the properties that are pointing to the same field in database. When doctrine loads entity from DB both properties filled. When doctrine persists entity to DB only `$administrator` value goes to DB.